# How disable html code optimizer in WordPress visual editor?

Tags: wordpress

I put in the tab "text" simple formatted code:

```
<div>
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Then I switch on tab "visual" and return on tab "text":

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

My code lose intend and span descriptor.
How I can disable this feature of visual editor wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code to your functions.php file and it should allow span tags:

```
function override_mce_options( $initArray ) {
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = 'span[style|id|nam|class|lang]';
    return $initArray;
} 
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but more important to me leave indents in html code.